# What's the difference between " and ' when creating strings in PHP?

Tags: php

Very basic, but would like to know the difference/security ramifications etc of using " vs. '.

Can someone provide an example that explains when to use each one?

Comment: Have you read the manual yet? http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: there are plenty of discussion on SO re those differences.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a lot of subtle differences, you'll want to read the [php documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) to get a lot of the details, but the important detail are:

Double quotes are parsed whereas single quotes are literals.

You can use variables inline with double quotes, but not with single quotes.

There are some catches though:

```
<?php
$beer = 'Heineken';
echo "$beer's taste is great"; // works; "'" is an invalid character for variable names
echo "He drank some $beers";   // won't work; 's' is a valid character for variable names but the variable is "$beer"
echo "He drank some ${beer}s"; // works
echo "He drank some {$beer}s"; // works
?>
```

Single quotes are slightly faster.

Comment: they are faster since php does not check the strings for vars

Comment: Right, because they are literals, not parsed strings.

Comment: it's worth pointing out that although yes, single quotes are faster, the difference is minuscule and shouldn't be overstated.

Comment: actually, looking at the results from http://phpbench.com/ - double quotes seem to (somehow) even perform better. in any case, it's not worth changing any habits over.

Comment: @nickf while correct, if you have large strings of static html for example it's worth using single quotes. it's also a good way to avoid accidental interpretation of variable names when you don't expect it.

Comment: PHP 4 had a huge speed difference in parsing single-quoted vs double-quoted strings. It was something like ten-times faster to concatenate strings and variables than to use embedded variable references in double-quotes. PHP 5 seems to have that bug fixed.

Answer (score 9):

When a string is enclosed in double quotes, then escape sequences such as `\n` and variable identifiers such as `$var` are interpreted.

See the [PHP strings manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) for specific details and examples.

Comment: +1 for including info about escape sequences, which no other answer here seems to have.

Answer (score 2):

The **biggest one** is this. Inside double-quotes, you can include variables, but inside single quotes, the variable name will be literal:

```
$var1 = "hello";

// this will echo "hello world"
echo "$var1 world";

// this will echo $var1 world
echo '$var1 world';
```

Using **double-quotes becomes extremely useful** in a number of situations, expecially when you place **{}** around the variable names. Here are some examples (*certainly others can give you more examples*):

```
// array elements
echo "Element 5 is {$myArray[5]}";
echo "Element 2 subelement 3 is {$myArray[2][3]}";
//
// a dynamic key 
$value = "thing";
$someValue = $myArray["some{$value}"]; // returnd $myArray[something]
```